# Echo variable which references another variable in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, bash-scripting, echo

Statement: `"$k"_Id_avg="$(grep -i "$k"_Id_avg file.txt)"`
and `$k` is a loop variable.
Now I want to print the value stored in the above variable, how can I do it?
I have tried `echo "$k"_Id_avg` but it prints only the variable name and replaces `$k` with the current loop value. eg: *NM_Id_avg*

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like:

```
varname="$k"_Id_avg
echo ${!varname}
```